# JPA @repository @Query Can handle a null entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am doing a project with `jpa` and `spring` , and i need to do a `query` like this:

```
Select models.dto.dealCalendarDTO(d, c) from deal d left outer join calendar c on calendar.deal_id=deal.id;
```

Or

```
Select d,c from deal d left outer join calendar c on calendar.deal_id=deal.id;
```

When I try the first one I have this error:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

When I use the second one, I have this one

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'c' {originalText=c}
```

I did it with classic `SQL` without a problem, but I think I am missing something.

Comment: what is table structure for deal and calendar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` in the first query because you are doing a left join and this maybe cause that c `Calendar` will be `null` and you are trying to access it in the `DTO` function